# Testing React: "Do not await the result of calling act(...) with sync logic"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, warnings, react-hooks

Using react and react-dom 16.9.0

I am getting this warning when I'm testing my react hooks:

```
console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:80
Warning: Do not await the result of calling act(...) with sync logic, it is not a Promise.
```

My test code (using jest with @testing-library/react)

```
...
await act( () => {
  rerender(
    <HookTester
      promise={asyncFunction}
      initialValue={'extra loading...'}
    />
  );
});

expect(asyncFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
...
```

But if I don't await, then my `expect`ation would be done too early.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Oh! I got it!

It turns out the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act) mention synchronous functions like this:

```
act( () => {
  // ... some 'sync logic'
});
```

which you can't await.

But you can await an async function of course:

```
await act( async () => {
  // ... some 'async logic'
});
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: this is what I don't like about RTL. All that async and await has made the testing code too verbose, and then you have to define the var that will hold the result of render outside of the act so you can assert outside of the act too, as you should

Comment: For a second I got excited that the docs may have actually been updated to include "async act" syntax, but alas no, still nothing about this important feature in the official docs.

Comment: For clarification, you must have React 16.9+ for this.

Comment: Yes. The first line says " Using react and react-dom 16.9.0"

Comment: Verbose, clear code is better than 'clean' code that requires lots and lots of context and convoluted syntactic sugar.

Comment: yeah.... async await is about as simple as you can get. don't understand the complaint

Comment: Been struggling for hours with the `overlaping act()` error and it seems I managed to solved it using this. Thanks!